# Json.loads() error "Invalid \escape" during load

Tags: python, json, session, response

I'm trying to parse a webpage in python but it keeps giving me an error during json parsing.
The web address is https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/ADIL/earnings-calendar. Browser seems to load without issue but when I try to parse the website in python I get:
"Invalid \escape: line 12 column 148 (char 3155)"

The JSON line it dies on is:
<span title=\"Theodore R O\'neill\" class=\"hotspot\">Theodore R O'ne..

I do see an invalid escape on the single quote "\'". But why does browser not show any errors and how do I avoid this when parsing the JSON from python?

Code snippet:

```
response = s.get(url, headers=requestHeader)
# Regex to find the earnings table values (?<=document\.obj_data = )[^{]*{\s+([^}]+)\s+}
regexMatch = re.search("(?<=document\.obj_data = )[^{]*{\s+([^}]+)\s+}",response.content.decode('utf-8'))

fullData = json.loads(regexMatch[0])  <<< Dies here.
```

Thanks!

Comment: BTW I'm currently implementing a workaround by which I convert all invalid escapes to valid ones... but I shouldn't have to do that is my feel.

Comment: _why does browser not show any errors_ Browsers are very forgiving and will render all kinds of broken html without complaining.

Answer (score -1):

```
#check this code
import requests as s
import regex as re
import json
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
requestHeader = {
    "User-Agent": ua.random
}

url = "https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/ADIL/earnings-calendar/"
response = s.get(url,headers=requestHeader)

print(response)
# Regex to find the earnings table values (?<=document\.obj_data = )[^{]*{\s+([^}]+)\s+}
regexMatch = re.search("(?<=document\.obj_data = )[^{]*{\s+([^}]+)\s+}",response.content.decode('utf-8'))
data = json.dumps(regexMatch[0])
fullData = json.loads(data)
print(fullData)
```